# Inno Setup runtime error: "" is not a valid integer value

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following code:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MyKey"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "MyValue"; ValueData: "{reg:HKLM\SomeKey,SomeValue}"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist;
```

and I got the error above when I run the installer. {reg:HKLM\SomeKey,SomeValue} above is a dword value. How can I fix this?

Comment: `SomeValue` key is of what type ? Does it exist ? Also, if it's possible that such key won't exist, you must provide a default value for the `{reg:}` constant. The statement that you give to the `ValueData` when `ValueType` is `dword` must evaluate to integer.

Comment: `SomeValue` is of dword type and does exist. I have other {reg:} constant that retrieves string value and it works well. So weird...

Comment: I was wrong in what I said. The statement that you pass to the `ValueData` can evaluate to something else than integer in case of `ValueType==dword`. It is the `{reg:...}` constant that returns a `DefaultValue` value for `REG_DWORD` key values. And since you've provided no default value, it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the [`{reg:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=reg) constant for value types other than `REG_SZ` or `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. This is quite hidden in a `DefaultValue` parameter description (emphasized by me):

> DefaultValue determines the string to embed if the specified registry
>   value does not exist, **or is not a string type (REG_SZ or
>   REG_EXPAND_SZ)**.

For you it means that you have to stop using a [`{reg:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=reg) constant for `REG_DWORD` value type registry keys. However, you can still write a [`{code:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) scripting function that will return the registry key value:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Registry]                                                                                      
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MyKey"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "MyValue"; ValueData: "{code:GetMyKeyValue}"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist;

[Code]
function GetMyKeyValue(Param: string): string;
var
  Value: DWORD;
begin
  // you should provide here a default integer value that will be used in case the key
  // value does not exist, otherwise you can end up with a similar error
  Result := '0';
  // query the registry key value and if it's found, return it
  if RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SomeKey', 'SomeValue', Value) then
    Result := IntToStr(Value);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I wish I could use the {reg:...} constant for integer type... It makes code cleaner.

Comment: You're welcome! I see. But you cannot use `{reg...}` for this at this time ([`here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L788) is really just a query for string key values). And I don't like the `{code...}` constant way I provided here (but it's the only scripting way you can use at this time). I would rather move all the registry creation entries into the `[Code]` section to have them all in one place. But you may file it as a feature request.